# How to pass non-english file-name to java main args by console?

Tags: java, windows, filesystems, registry, windows-console

I have developed a simple java program that renames filenames that passed to it in args against a pre-defined pattern. I have registered my program in the **right-click context menu** of files.

**Usage**

When right-clicking on the file and choose my program **Mark as** from it, the file renaming successfully if its name is in English chars, but if it contains only 1 non-English char it results and error because these chars passed to args and **?** so there is no file with this name.

the original file name:

[image: the original file name]

[image]

**How to fix these "?" in the case of non-English chars?**

Comment: Could you describe how you created that `Mark as ..` option? Maybe there are settings/options which needs to be changed.

Comment: @Pshemo I don't think because it works correctly in the English chars

Comment: While your program is still running, take a look at the command line in Task Manager or Process Explorer. This is the Unicode command line that's passed to your program. If it looks correct, then the problem is with how your Java program handles the command line.

Comment: I have registered it in "Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell" with the name **test** and the value of **"Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\test\command"** is **"exe path" "%1"**

Comment: @AmmarYasser I am not an expert on that matter (registry etc..) but maybe it is running because some *default* settings are set to support English characters (just a guess). If that is the case the maybe some other options need to changed/enabled. I don't know how to achieve that but maybe some expert will notice something after seeing how your application is actually run.

Comment: @Pshemo Ok thank you

Comment: @ErykSun my problem lies in the default charset of **windows-console** that passes the file name to java. I have just tried to write some **Arabic** chars in windows-console but as expected they appeared as **?**. Here we almost define the problem, but how to solve it? IDK :)

Comment: Did you inspect the command line in Task Manager or Process Explorer like I asked? Because your assumption makes no sense. The console has nothing to do with the command line that's passed to your application by the Windows shell. And, for what you tried, assuming you're using the CMD shell, it reads UTF-16 from the console via `ReadConsoleW` and runs applications via `CreateProcessW`. If your Java program garbles the Unicode command line, then Java is likely using the the ANSI encoded command line from `GetCommandLineA`. To repeat, first verify the actual command line using an external tool.

Comment: @ErykSun, Ok I will do but how? can you provide me with a link?

Comment: In Windows 8+ the Processes tab of Task Manager should have a "Command Line" field. If it's not visible, right click the column headings and enable it in the context menu. When your Java program is displaying the error box, it's still running, so you should be able to find it listed in the processes.

Comment: @ErykSun, Inspection done! and the result as I expected the **path of the file was interrupted** with _?_ instead of the Arabic chars. what can I do now?

Comment: For which case, when run from the CMD shell or when run directly from Explorer on the right-click context menu, or both? Run the command line directly from the Win+R menu and check the command line in Task Manager again.

Comment: @ErykSun, I tried again just now and the same **error still appears**. I need run from **right-click** menu but I think if we fix the run from CMD we will be able to fix right-click.

Comment: Maybe something is coming in between the command you run and the eventual command that spawns the process. Please run [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer). Click on the "Process" tab in the column headers until it displays a tree view. In the right-hand side enable the "Command Line" column, and share a screen shot that includes the shell and your process, with both command lines visible. If there's no longer a tree relationship between your process and the shell, then something else intervened.

Comment: @ErykSun Here is the [screenshot](https://imgur.com/gallery/fN7tZlm)

Comment: It appears to be what I thought. Your "Mark as.exe" is some kind of launcher. It apparently has an embedded jar file, and it spawns a javaw.exe process. Notice that this javaw.exe process is not linked as a child of the cmd.exe shell. That's because its parent, "Mark as.exe" has already exited after running javaw.exe with the `-jar` option, the path to your executable, and the rest of the command line. This launcher is the culprit. It's using the legacy command line from `GetCommandLineA` instead of the native Unicode command line from `GetCommandLineW`.

Comment: BTW, when you see the default box glyph in the console, that's not necessarily mojibake (gibberish and question marks). The console window is limited to the available glyphs in its current font. It doesn't have automatic font fallback, and it can't display complex scripts and non-BMP characters (i.e. characters with ordinals above 65535). Even if it doesn't display properly, you should be able to copy and paste it into another window such as notepad, which uses modern text controls that support font fallback, complex scripts, and non-BMP characters.

Comment: @Eryk Sun, how to stop it from exiting ? And make it uses **GetCommandLineW** instead of **GetCommandLineA** ?

Answer (score -1):

A method online I found. This should work for your issue also. 
https://howtodoinjava.com/eclipse/how-to-display-non-english-unicode-e-g-chinese-characters-in-eclipse/

or

https://forum.processing.org/one/topic/japanese-characters-in-processing.html#25080000002303153.html

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: This is more suited as a comment.

Comment: @Kyle Flores, I use *IntelliJ IDEA* and it read and print Arabic chars correctly. **my problem not in the IDE** but lies in the **windows-console** that passes the file name to java. *Overall thank you for your contribution*

Comment: Wasn't aware of the standards of comments versus answers. I hadn't read that previous article concerning comments versus answers. However, I was not asking for clarification. Since this -> "Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post. Outdated comments may get deleted. Learn more about comments…" is directly below as I am typing. So according to that "standard" I was correct due to not asking a question. You're welcome Ammar, I had seen another part about having to update the console for a similar configuration, if found, I'll link.